# How can I embed an excel spreadsheet in a C# program

Tags: excel, embed

I've been trying to use the ActiveX control axOWC10.axSpreadsheet but I can't figure out how to specify the DataSource and DataMember properties. Should I not be using this particular ActiveX control?

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will allow you to embed an Excel workbook in a C# program. You can download the free evaluation [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 0):

How about [this tutorial?](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/csharp_excel.aspx)

EDIT:
Sorry, I think this opens up Excel in a separate window. That's not what you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the XML file as datasource like

```
spreadSheet.XMLURL = _filePath;
```